# Seamless facebook login experience for iOS using Custom URL Scheme

Tags: facebook, ios, facebook-graph-api

How can one login to Facebook from an app using the Custom URL scheme?
Some apps like AppsFire does it. Instead of integrating FB-Connect within the app, they launch facebook app and login there. Once logged in, your app gets a call back.

Is anyone aware of the "private" custom URL scheme for this?

This doesn't help much...
http://iphonedevtools.com/?p=302

Comment: http://chings228.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/facebook-login-for-ios-part-1-singleton/ i have written a tutorial for facebook login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question...
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk