# how to oauth login facebook through native Facebook?

Tags: facebook, oauth

Usually we use the pop-up webview connect facebook on iphone apps.
However, I have seen some applications, auth link to facebook by facebook native app,If the iphone is already installed on the official app.
how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your app would include the iOS or Android SDK for Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/

Specifically how to login with iOS:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

And Android:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

This is done through the Facebook iOS SDK, available on GitHub here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

This is seamless, and Facebook handles the case if the app is installed on the device. This is done with the "fb://" URL scheme. You can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756728/seamless-facebook-login-experience-for-ios-using-custom-url-scheme)

To authenticate on Facebook with the SDK, you do this:

```
Facebook *facebook = [[Facebook alloc] init];
NSArray *fb_perms =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"user_photos", @"offline_access",nil];
[facebook authorize:fb_perms delegate:self];
```

Don't forget to release!

Comment: hi~  Facebook hasn't authorize:delegate: this method~